# Variable without $, can it be possible?

Tags: php, parsing, variables, syntax-error

is it possible that a variable is referenced without using the $?

For example:

```
if ($a != 0 && a == true) {
...
}
```

I don't think so, but the code (not written by me) doesn't show an error and I think it's weird. I've overlooked the code and a is not a constant either.

Comment: try: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);` And php will tell you that it couldn't find `$a` and will instead use a literal `a` (meaning the character a) for the comparsion.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Michael already includes this point and he even has a better explanation. ;P

Comment: @Yoshi: Oh, he didn't at the time ;)

Comment: I've just inherited a site that has *hundreds* of lines like:  $lastRequest = $userArray[lastRequest];
They tell me the site worked fine at one point...I'm scratching my head...HOW? Glad to see someone else had a similar issue here, at least I feel better now.

Comment: @PeterG It would have worked fine if `error_reporting` was set to exclude `E_NOTICE`.  The unquoted array key `lastRequest` would be converted to the string `'lastRequest'` by PHP, if there was no currently defined constant of the same name.  PHP does this to help you out, but it is a nuisance that encourages sloppy programming habits.  It still should work properly (unless a constant was defined) but would throw a lot of errors.

Comment: @PeterG I feel sorry for you.  People get into bad habits, especially when they have `display_errors` turned off and don't know what problems they're missing.  You could, if you were brave, use `sed` to quote all the unquoted array keys in one go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In PHP, a constant can be defined, which would then not have a `$`, but a variable must have one.  However, this is NOT a variable, and is not a substitute for a variable.  Constants are intended to be defined exactly once and not changed throughout the lifetime of the script.

```
define('a', 'some value for a');
```

Additionally, you cannot interpolate the value of a constant inside a double-quoted or HEREDOC string:

```
$a = "variable a"
define('a', 'constant a');

echo "A string containing $a";
// "A string containing variable a";

// Can't do it with the constant
echo "A string containing a";
// "A string containing a";
```

Finally, PHP may issue a notice for an `Use of undefined constant a - assumed 'a'` and interpret it as a mistakenly unquoted string `"a"`.  Look in your error log to see if that is happening.  In that case, `"a" == TRUE` is valid, since the string `"a"` is non-empty and it is compared loosely to the boolean TRUE.

```
echo a == TRUE ? 'true' : 'false';
// Prints true
// PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant a - assumed 'a'
```

Comment: On top of that, by default if PHP sees an undefined constant it will assume a constant with the value of the string. With your example of a, PHP will interpret that as a constant named a, with a value of 'a' (as a string). This does cause a notice or something: increase your error reporting value to see it.

Comment: @Narcissus thanks - already added while you were typing your comment :)

Comment: What about using magic methods? Ie: __get -- Would this make having a variable name without a dollar sign possible?

Comment: @KevinWheeler No. The magic methods apply to class properties, so they would always be in a context like `$obj->magic_get_property`. They can't be used at global scope.

Answer (score 2):

With this code:

```
if ($a != 0 && a == true) {
    ...
}
```

You're not getting any error because you (or someone else) have told PHP to not report any errors, warnings or notices with that code. You set error reporting to a higher level and you will get a notice:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant a - assumed 'a' in ...

Which will mean that `a` is read as a constant with a value of `"a"`. This is not what you're actually looking for I guess:

```
if ($a != 0 && "a" == true) {
    ...
}
```

The second part `"a" == true` will always be `true`, so this is actually like so:

```
if ($a != 0) {
    ...
}
```

As it's not your code, one can only assume that this was not intended by the original author.

So: Variables in PHP always start with the dollar sign `$`. Everything else is not a variable.

Answer (score 1):

By definition a variable MUST start with a $. Also, it **cannot** start with a number so a variable name like $1badVar is invalid. It may however, start with letters or underscores.