# PHP/javascript script stops working when I include a php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

New to javascript. I have been learning a lot over the past few days.

I have a script that loads a calendar. The calendar layout is built in php. I have the following code:

```
jQuery.get(PLUGIN_DIR+'/bookings/reservation.php', function(data)
{
    jQuery('#content_div').html(data);
});
```

Reservation.php

```
<?php

echo '</div><div class="box_div" id="reservation_div"><div class="box_top_div" id="reservation_top_div"><div id="reservation_top_left_div"><a href="." id="previous_week_a">&lt; Previous week</a></div><div id="reservation_top_center_div">Reservations for week <span id="week_number_span">' . global_week_number . '</span></div><div id="reservation_top_right_div"><a href="." id="next_week_a">Next week &gt;</a></div></div><div class="box_body_div"><div id="reservation_table_div"></div></div></div><div id="reservation_details_div">';

?>
```

The above works fine. However when I add the following include to define global_week_number it stops working.

```
<?php

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/plugins/bookings/js/header-js.php');

echo '</div><div class="box_div" id="reservation_div"><div class="box_top_div" id="reservation_top_div"><div id="reservation_top_left_div"><a href="." id="previous_week_a">&lt; Previous week</a></div><div id="reservation_top_center_div">Reservations for week <span id="week_number_span">' . global_week_number . '</span></div><div id="reservation_top_right_div"><a href="." id="next_week_a">Next week &gt;</a></div></div><div class="box_body_div"><div id="reservation_table_div"></div></div></div><div id="reservation_details_div">';

?>
```

The include file is header-js.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
echo "PLUGIN_DIR = '".plugins_url()."';";
echo "global_css_animations = ".global_css_animations.";";
echo "global_week_number = ".global_week_number.";";
?>
</script>
```

I am at a loss here. I have no idea why it stops working when I include header-js.php. Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: So how does the PHP generated JS look like? AND, your variables are wrong, miss `$` sign.

Comment: do you have any obvious errors in the browsers console (in general hit f12 to open)?

Comment: Are `global_css_animations` and `global_week_number` PHP constants? If not, they need to be preceded by `$` when referencing them as PHP variables. (i.e. `echo "global_week_number = ".$global_week_number.";";`)

Comment: So you are including Javascript code in the AJAX call. Why? The defined JS variables won't be available in your main layout.

Comment: @djot actually I don't think you can say the php variables are WRONG. Isn't the $ before the variable name a convention? Not a requirement?

Comment: @scrappedcola no javascript errors in the console.

Comment: I don't know what you talk of, but this looks like it should be PHP variables: `".global_week_number.";"`

Comment: @Divey global_css_animations and global_week_number are calculated at run time by a php script. They are not constants. And they work fine in other parts of the code. I believe the $ before PHP variables is more a convention than a requirement. The code should still work. Am I right?

Comment: @djot they are PHP variables. They work fine without the $ in front in other parts of the code.

Comment: The `$` is required by the interpreter. It is not only a convention. If you do not have the `$` it is considered a constant and not a variable.

Comment: This gets the idea in one place: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147868/variable-without-can-it-be-possible but it's also stated in the php manual...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just figured out the problem.

It was not the lack of $ before the variables' names. Although I do agree with the comments that I should use it.

The problem was that I was calling a function plugins_url() that is available only within the Wordpress framework. I didn't have problems until now because all my php scripts were running as custom pages inside Wordpress - so plugins_url() was always available.

The moment I called a php script using jQuery.get(reservation.php) the function plugins_url() was not defined and caused an error.

I have two options - load the Wordpress framework with the reservation.php script or avoid using wordpress functions. I opted for the second.

Thanks.